# How to prevent an item to be sorted (fix positon) in Kendo Sortable / Integration - ListView?

Tags: javascript, events, kendo-listview, kendo-sortable

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: anArray
    })

var listView = $("#listView").kendoListView({
    name: "listView",
    tagname: "div",
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template: kendo.template($("#listview-template").html()),
});

listView.kendoSortable({
        filter: ">div.myclass",
        cursor: "move",
        placeholder: function (element) {
            return element.clone().addClass("placeholder").text("position here")
        },
        hint: function (element) {
            return element.clone().removeClass("k-state-selected");
        },
        change or move or end?: function(e){
            if(e.newIndex==35){
                 --e.newIndex;
                 console.log(e.newIndex); //output is 34, but the element is moved to 35
            }
        }
});
```

I want to prevent that the dragged item can be inserted after an itemA (instead, it could be inserted to the previous index) and also that itemA cannot be dragged.

**So itemA has to stay fixed on its position.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and here is a demo: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/filter-disable 
.

For my specific case:
There is no need to modify e.newIndex.

With `filter: "div.myclass.sortable"`, I allow that only divs with the class "sortable" are sortable.
I give all div.myclass elements the class sortable (in my Kendo-listview-template).

For preventing a div to be sorted, I search it and remove the class sortable:

```
var sortableItems = $(".sortable");
var nonSortableItem = sortableItems[35];               

nonSortableItem.classList.remove("sortable"); //now that one stays fix
```

---

If you just want that you cannot move an item (but it does not have to stay fix when other items move), you have to use **disable** instead of filter (@see also in the demo above).